# Mod_rewrite: two rules with same regexp, serve first or second if 404 raises (aka last resort rule)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have simple .htaccess, which implements front controller pattern (i.e. redirects non static requests to index.php)

Rules for serve for page and news by url.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/$ /index.php?action=page&url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/$ /index.php?action=news&url=$1
```

If there is no page with passed url (i.e. 404 error raises), I need serve news.

I want assign 2 rules to 1 regexp: if first rule returns 404, try second. I know alternative ways:

1. Use two rules with different regexp, as @Starkeen noted.
2. Deligate login to actual handler (in my case it's php).

May I achieve this behavior with `.htaccess/mod_rewrite`?

**P.S.** I decided don't overcomplicate things and to implement variant 1.

Comment: Do you want to redirect all 404 to news page?

Comment: Thanks for comment. No, it's very simplified example. I want assign 2 rules to 1 regexp: if first rule returns 404, try second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using same pattern for both rules, that is why the first is being processed and the second being ignored.

change  pattern for both rules

```
RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9_]+)/?$ /index.php?action=page&url=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-z0-9_]+)/?$ /index.php?action=news&url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now you can use your urls as :

```
example.com/page/foo
example.com/news/foo
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Before asking I thought about splitting my rule into 2. I also thought about deligating aforementioned logic to actual handler (in my case it's php). But desirable behaviour is news and page were on the same level, i.e. example.com/page-or-news-url

Comment: I decided don't overcomplicate things and to implement your variant.

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite will only kick in if there is not an existing file or directory in the location.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?action=news&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `-f` flag will make the rewrite only kick in if the file doesn't exist, and the `-d` flag will ensure the rewrite won't kick in if a directory exists there.